# How can I show only one item from current position to horizontal RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have horizontal RecyclerView which has GridView. When I scroll RecyclerView, 2 elements appear at the same time. I just want to show the item at the current position.

**Activity:**

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, getTotalCount()));
```

**My adapter:**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private int count;
    private Context context;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int count) {
        this.context = context;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(ViewUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, R.layout.my_recyclerView));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyGridViewAdapter myGridViewAdapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(position);
        holder.gridView.setAdapter(myGridViewAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return count;
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private GridView gridView;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            gridView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi propoLis, plz try to set the height of the recyclerView list item to `match_parent` and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/PagerSnapHelper)

```
val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Always use "wrap_content" for the height of the row otherwise in "match_parent" it will occupy the whole screen for a single row.

2-You can also take the height in dp.

Comment: please add you layout